# How can I read JSON files into a MongoDB collection which can be queried?

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a folder with hundreds of JSON files in it.
Each file is essentially a single record - a JSON object containing the details of a person.
Here is an example of what three files might look like:

**record1.json**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("609d1ce7ca3840259eed1da5"),
        "first_name" : "Abdulrahman",
        "nationality" : "dz"
}
```

**record2.json**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("609d1df5ca3840259eed1da6"),
        "first_name" : "Tony",
        "nicknames" : [
                "Biggus Dickus",
                "Tarzan",
                "Mogli",
                "King of the Jungle"
        ],
        "age" : 21
}
```

**record3.json**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("609d20fd8bc03bb4492cd24a"),
        "first_name" : "Mary",
        "last_name" : "Jane",
        "age" : 19,
        "gender" : "f"
}
```

How can I gather all these files into a MongoDB collection which can be queried from inside a mongo shell? I want to be able to execute commands like db.contacts.find().pretty()
Also, what is the best practice for naming each file?

Comment: [`mongoimport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#mongoimport) is your friend

Comment: Since, you have multiple JSON files, you may want to combine all the JSON data into one file (or a JSON array) and do the import. Another option is, you can also use a programming language (write your own program) to import data into MongoDB database.